Wireguard VPN traffic *to* AWS works, but traffic *from* AWS to that VPN IP never arrives
I have a Wireguard server running in an EC2 instance in a public subnet of a VPC. I can connect to it, and use SSH or other things on resources in both the public and private subnets in that VPC.
However, I can't get traffic to run the other direction. From the server (10.8.0.1) I can't ping the connected Windows VPN client (10.8.0.2) or even traceroute to it. Both time out.
The route table on the Windows client shows
 10.8.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.2      5
 10.8.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.2    261

and on the Wireguard server shows
[root@ip-10-0-0-202 wireguard]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-10-0-0-1.us- 0.0.0.0         UG    512    0        0 enX0
ip-10-0-0-0.us- 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     512    0        0 enX0
ip-10-0-0-1.us- 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    512    0        0 enX0
ip-10-0-0-2.us- 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    512    0        0 enX0
ip-10-8-0-0.us- 0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wg0

The security group the Wireguard server is in has allowAllEgress and I can access resources on the open Internet from there. The Windows firewall is (for testing) fully disabled, and ping works against it from another machine on its LAN.
The route table for the security group the server is in shows 10.8.0.0/16 having the target as the network interface for the VPN server itself.
Edit:
I've done iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 -d 10.0.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE, and also sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward gives the answer 1.
Edit 2:
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-202 ~]$ sudo iptables -L FORWARD -v -n
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
14819 3075K ACCEPT     all  --  wg0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
15119   56M ACCEPT     all  --  *      wg0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wg0    wg0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wg0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

The end goal is to allow an ALB in the same VPC to forward certain HTTP requests to the VPN server, which is running nginx and will forward those requests on to the connected VPN client. The requests arrive at the Wireguard server but never make it out to the client.
What could I be doing wrong?

To allow the WireGuard server to route packets between the VPN interface and the rest of the network (or back to the VPN client), IP forwarding must be enabled. And since the WireGuard server and VPN client are on different subnets, NAT might be required.

I've done
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/16 -d 10.0.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
and also
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
gives the answer 1

Do your iptables FORWARD chain rules allow the packets to go through?

I'm not positive how to know. Here's what I see:
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-202 ~]$ sudo iptables -L FORWARD -v -n Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 14819 3075K ACCEPT     all  --  wg0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0 15119   56M ACCEPT     all  --  *      wg0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wg0    wg0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0     0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wg0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
